# Nightwatch testing with Selenium 2 JSON?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to run Selenium 2 formmated tests, via Nightwatch, that have been exported from GhostInspector?

I have Nightwatch setup in my repo to start selenium and run the demo test. How can I pass it the json formatted Selenium test?

The test files are formatted as such:

```
{
    "type": "script",
    "seleniumVersion": "2",
    "formatVersion": 2,
    "steps": [
        {
            "type": "get",
            "url": "https://domain.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "get",
            "url": "/somepage
        },
        {
            "type": "assertEval",
            "script": "return Boolean( document.getElementById('header') );",
            "value": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The current Demo test, opens then closes the browser:

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test' : function (browser) {
        browser
            .url(browser.launchUrl)
            // ...
            .end();
    }
};
```